# Sequences and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let (a<sub>n</sub>) be a sequence with a<sub>n</sub>>0 for all natural numbers n. Assume that lim(a<sub>n</sub>)=0. Show that the set of all numbers a<sub>n</sub> has a maximum. That is, show that there is some number p, such that a<sub>n</sub> <=a<sub>p</sub>.

> > My idea: after a certain point all elements will tend toward 0 since lim(a<sub>n</sub>)=0. At that point, take the maximum of the elements of (a<sub>n</sub>) before that point. That is all I have so far. I need help with writing out the details...

Comment: Your idea is right, now use the definition of a limit.

Comment: You can also show that if there is no maximum, then $\limsup{x_n} \not=0$, providing a contradiction.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE I love that idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convergence dictates that there is a value $N$ such that $\forall n > N \ : \ a_n < \frac{a_1}{2}$, i.e. we chose $\epsilon = \frac{a_1}{2}$. Now the set $\{a_n | n \leq N\}$ is finite, thus has a maximum which is obviously also the maximum of the entire sequence.